# Crosstab Sorting in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I have a column group in a Crosstab that is a String.

It uses the field **`SectionName`**.

There is another field, **`SectionID`** (Integer), that I want to sort by.

I put **`$F{SectionID}`** in the *`Sort By Expression`* but I get the error:

> *1. Field not found : SectionID*

This field is in the dataset. I can add a group on this field and display it. When I try to use it in sorting I get the error.

Is it possible to display one field in the column group header but sort by another?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasper Reports crosstab sorting with comparatorExpression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314780/jasper-reports-crosstab-sorting-with-comparatorexpression)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to create another row group for you SectionID and make sure it is first -tweak in the XML - and then remove the text box from the visual display